# Transfer the combination formula into VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a formula in excel, that is combination between IF statement, vlookup and they formula will be application in all cell using looping coding.

this the formula :

```
= IF((VLOOKUP(G4;$A$4:$B$9;2;FALSE))=1;"terhubung";IF((VLOOKUP(G4;$A$4:$C$9;3;FALSE))=1;"unreach";IF((VLOOKUP(G4;$A$4:$D$9;4;FALSE))=1;"reject";IF((VLOOKUP(G4;$A$4:$E$9;5;FALSE))=1;"workload";""))))
```

explanation about the formula, I try capture in this image.
[image: image description here]

The question is how to the formula can transfer into the vba coding using button_click

Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff193019

Comment: Code to modify other code is a non-trivial task and there are a few Google results out there for "vba to modify another project".

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your formula with the following one...

```
=INDEX($B$3:$E$3,MATCH(1,INDEX($B$4:$E$9,MATCH(G4,$A$4:$A$9,0),),0))
```

If you want to insert the formula through VBA and keep the values only, you may try something like below.

```
Sub InsertFormula()
    Range("H4:H9").Formula = "=INDEX($B$3:$E$3,MATCH(1,INDEX($B$4:$E$9,MATCH(G4,$A$4:$A$9,0),),0))"
    Range("H4:H9").Value = Range("H4:H9").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: one question again, how about this formula and keep the values, I can insert in all cell in one rows. Like a vlookup function and the lookup value can moves automatically. Please the advise. Using looping or how you think.

Comment: I am unsure of what you are asking here. But the proposed formula and VBA code are dynamic enough to identify the lookup value in the range G4:G9 and identify their position in the lookup range A4:A9 and will get you the correct column header even if you move the lookup value up or down in the range.

Comment: Thanks very much sktneer for your advise. I will try it, hope the answer.

Comment: You're welcome Hendriawan! It that helped, please take a moment to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.